# how to prevent added meta box from being injected with style="position: fixed; top: 56px;" at scroll down

Tags: javascript, jquery, metabox

This is my first attempt to customize WordPress.

I added a meta box like this

```
function settings_metabox() {
    //register custom meta box
    add_meta_box("mybox-id", "Settings", "settings_callback_function", "blog", "side", "high");
}
add_action("add_meta_boxes", "settings_metabox");
```

but somehow the meta box div gets injected with `style="position: fixed; top: 56px;"` when I start to scroll down; and the meta box jumps to the back of the other meta boxes.

This is what it looks like:

[image: new meta box]

---

And when scrolling down it turns to this:

[image: meta box after scrolling down on page]

How can I prevent this.

Answer (score 0):

I found a temporary workaround by doing this

```css
<style>
div #my_meta_box {
    background: #c0cdd7;
    position: relative !important;
    z-index: initial;
}
div #submitdiv {
    z-index: initial;
}
#postbox-container-2 {
    width: calc(100% - 300px)  !important;;
}
#wpfooter {
    display: none;
}
</style>
```